# Is there a central Boston unpopulated location that contains all the crafting stations?

Tags: fallout-4

I was wondering whether there's a unpopulated (or containing clearable hostiles) location in central Boston in Fallout 4 that contains the following:

- Weapons workbench
- Armour workbench
- Chemistry station
- Cooking station
- Power armour station (optional, but useful)

From memory University Point might offer all of these but I'm looking for a location closer to Downtown Boston.

This is for a character I'm playing who avoids people/ populated settlements. The character doesn't have the "Local Leader" perk so they can't build crafting stations in Hangman Alley (which is an excellent location).

Of course if a suitable location has hostile inhabitants I can always clear them out.

I'd also like to avoid loading screens by having to enter buildings/ subways etc. if possible.

Comment: So if you want to avoid people, I guess going to Diamond City won't work? You can find all the stations/workbenches there.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault - yes, for the sake of playing an anti-social/ people adverse character Diamond City and Goodneighbor are out.

Comment: @DCShannon Given the character, I think Hangman's Alley is appropriate because (after clearing) it starts out deserted and you don't have to build a recruitment beacon to claim it. Really a great home for the anti-social sort, though it may be of limited use if you can't build crafting stations.

Comment: @DCShannon So far, I've only come up with [Cambridge Baseball Diamond](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Cambridge_Baseball_Diamond).

Comment: @DCShannon - CBD is an acronym for "Central Business District". I'm a New Zealander and the term is pretty common here. I didn't realise it wasn't widely used and have updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: @DCShannon - before you made this comment I'd updated the question to specify "non-populated" rather than "non-settlement" - although this cause confusion about a location occupied by Raiders/ Super Mutants etc. - which could be cleared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Combat Zone](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Combat_Zone) is an hostile area located pretty much centrally on the map, in the Theatre District of South Boston. It's south of Swan's Pond and east of Trinity Tower.

Inside, once you get past the lobby, you have a cooking station on your left. A chemistry station can be found in the first building on the right. The first building on the left contains an armor and weapon workbench.

There's a potential companion inside and another NPC that cannot be killed, but you can avoid them completely as the stations are located pretty far from them.

Inside of Combat Zone:

---

For your Power Armor station, if you go a little south-east you can use Slim's workshops. There's a Power Armor station, Weapon workshop and Chemistry station. You can easily dispose of him.

Slim's workshops are located west of Hesters Consumer Robotics and south of Mass Bay Medical Center, right where my character stands:

[image: Workshops]

Comment: Good find, but I think the presence of the unkillable NPC probably disqualifies it.

Comment: @DCShannon They can be very easily avoided, the workbenches are nowhere near the ring. And at least it's located centrally on the map and in Boston, contrary to the extremely far Red Rocket Truck Stop.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault - great find. Will check it out tonight.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault That's a good point about the location. +1 for that.

Comment: Is the "it" in your last sentence referring to Slim's workshop? The Combat Zone is the icon with the two little tent/house looking things to the NW, right?

Comment: @DCShannon Yeah, updated the sentence. And yes, Combat Zone is NW of there, as shown on the wiki page I linked to. There's no picture for the location of Slim on the wiki, so I added my own.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault - Thank you for the answer. I've included a Youtube video of the inside of the Combat Zone showing the Crafting Stations in your answer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S7tlH6QNZiE

Answer (score 4):

Nukapedia has a list of all [Fallout 4 settlements](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_settlements), which includes icons to indicate which stations are pre-built in each.

Based on that list, there are only three settlements which come already fully-equipped as you desire. Fortunately, one of them is abandoned (perfect for your anti-social character) and is accessible very early in the game.

- ***Red Rocket Truck Stop***
- Sanctuary Hills
- The Castle

There are some other non-settlement locations which are pretty well-equipped, but none in particular come immediately to mind. Besides, anti-social or not, I'm sure your character would still like to have their go-to workstations close to a place that they can fully customize themselves and call "home". Also, it's worth noting that storage containers outside of settlements tend to be less reliable for long-term use.

Comment: The  Sunshine Tidings Co-Op is also practically abandoned.

Comment: There are links to pages for each type of crafting station on Nukapedia [here](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_crafting). Some of those list locations where you can find the workbenches. They don't look complete right now, but I don't see any non-settlement location that has all the stations from the information currently listed.

Comment: @aslum The Co-Op doesn't have all the crafting stations.

Comment: @DCShannon I'm pretty sure there's at least one or two non-settlement locations with all the stations, especially if you drop the (declared optional) requirement for a power armor rack. They're probably not extremely convenient to a fast-travel point though.

Comment: @Iszi I wouldn't be surprised if there was one, I'm just saying that there doesn't appear to be one based on currently available information. I'm supporting your answer. I think someone on PC could probably use the console and figure out where they all are and add it to the wiki if they wanted, but I'm not going to ask anybody to go to all that work.

Comment: @DCShannon Yeah, Nukapedia is *far* from complete in regards to listing all the workbench locations. If I think of it next time I'm on, I'll check around a few likely suspects. Would also be helpful to know what the "CBD" is.

Comment: @Iszi I know Fort Hagen has all of the stations throughout the complex, and numerous Power Armor Stations, to boot. I believe the fallout wiki for that location tells where each station is. The complex is big, so the stations are spread out... and it's not very centrally located... but it might work.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't quite answer my original question but I thought it was interesting enough to post.

Redditer/Youtuber "The_Lawd" has been [documenting all of the secondary locations in Fallout 4](https://www.reddit.com/r/gaming/comments/5528iw/i_explored_and_documented_every_single_unmarked/).

He made [a video about the Tinkerer's Boathouse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oRTZxJch9ys) on the Boston Waterfront which contains the following:

- Weapons Workbench
- Chemistry Workbench
- Power Armour Station

Not quite what I was after, but a very useful hideout and worth mentioning.